# Can anyone suggest a free alternative to Corbel font for web use

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, web-fonts, free

Corbel:

> [image]

I've been searching for hours and hours, now days for a font that would fit my website as Corbel does. I know it might not look like the best font, but it fits my needs. I've found Ubuntu that is pretty similar, I tried "Open sans" of course, "Source sans", and even the good old verdana, which is not free...etc..

But none works.

Verdana is not free, and has a very ugly bold version.

Ubuntu is not looking good to me when you size it up, and not sharp enough when you size it down.

Open sans could have been the perfect match but the characters are a bit too squared compared to Corbel which has more rounded characters, and low profile lowercase characters.

I've tried Quicksand but the character's space is not good, even if I would want to use letter-spacing to fix this, it doesn't work.

Has anyone ever tried to find a good Corbel alternative?

EDIT: The closest I've found yet is "Quattrocento Sans" available on google font. It has the same spirit/feeling. Despite the fact that I don't like the G letter, I know i'm crazy.

Corbel:14px / Quattrocento Sans:13.5px

[Google Font Collection that could match](https://www.google.com/fonts#ReviewPlace:refine/Collection:Roboto:100,100italic,300,300italic,400,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic%7CHind:300,400,500,600,700%7CQuattrocento+Sans:400,700%7CCantarell:400,700%7CKhula:400,300,600,700,800%7CCambay:400,700%7CMallanna%7CSource+Sans+Pro:400,200,200italic,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,900,900italic%7CUbuntu:400,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic)

**EDIT 2: Actually not good enough**

Comment: including an image of the font wouldn't be a bad idea. :)

Comment: Sorry about that, edited!

Comment: The screenshots doesn't show how light and crispy it is.

Comment: Have you tried : http://www.identifont.com/similar?LKU
seems that there are a few look alikes..
:)

Comment: I know it's not what you want to hear, but if it's really _that_ important that the font not really look any different then why not just pay to use Corbel? From MyFonts it costs 120 dollars for Corbel, Corbel Italic, Corbel Bold, and Corbel Bold Italic for up to 250,030 page views. Assuming this is a personal site, 250,030 page views will last a long time (most likely) or if it's for a business then they should be able to cover the fee. Alternatively you'll have to settle for a font that just doesn't have the exact same feel as every font is unique.

Comment: Corbel is a Humanist Sans. Perhaps that will help you in your research.

Comment: Despite being proprietary, Verdana is ‘free’ in the sense that you generally don’t have to include it as a webfont—it’s already installed on the vast majority of non-Linux desktop machines, and even on Linux boxes, it’s quite likely to be installed ([this page](http://dry.sailingissues.com/linux-equivalents-verdana-arial.html) says ~53%, but that’s five years old).

Comment: Another option: Fetch yourself a copy of FontForge and fix the G to your likes in Quattrocento Sans. (But check the license, if this is legal.)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Specimen]

Maybe Amble could do the work:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/amble

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still looking but "Cantarell" is what you're looking for. It is similar to Corbel, they both have that "English" Gill Sans influence and both use single bowl "g"s as opposed to the other fonts suggested. It is available on FontSquirrel and as a Google font.

[image: Cantarell sample]

Answer (score 0):

Liberation Sans has some similarities to Corbel. You can find it on Font Squirrel and there are four styles (regular, italic, bold & bold-italic): http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Liberation-Sans

Answer (score 0):

Although Corbel is a Humanist sans, as [DA01 commented](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57009/can-anyone-suggest-a-free-alternative-to-corbel-font-for-web-use#comment90053_57009), you may find that other fonts provide a similar feel, for example **Corbert,** also via Font Squirrel. This is their image; the leading could be larger:

[image: Corbert]

[Corbert on Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/corbert)

Unfortunately there is no native bold variant, so you will be forced into resorting to faux-bold.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same question and after more digging I found [Noto Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Noto+Sans) from Google Fonts.

[image: Noto Sans closest to Corbel]